# Read write lock with condition variables

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a fifo queue that I have implemented, it has two methods `add()` and `remove()` both of which perform write operation on queue. To make it thread safe I am using `ReentrantLock`. I have two conditions, (i) block a thread if the queue is empty and its trying to remove; (ii) block a thread if the queue is full and its trying to add. Now, I want to implement a peek operation, which would allow multiple threads to perform simultaneous peeks but no thread would be able to write. If I use `ReentrantLock` I cannot achieve that since I have to acquire the lock and its mutually exclusive. I can do peek operation in `ReentrantReadWriteLock` but it doesn't come with condition variables which I need. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you provide some code you will have more chances to get an answer

Comment: ReentrantReadWriteLock  has a property writeLock() which has method newCondition().

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov Thank you, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Why does `peek()` need a lock at all?

It is *impossible* for `peek()` to give a guaranteed correct answer.

```
if (q.peek() != NULL) {
    ... q could be empty at this point because some other consumer
        could have removed the last item after the peek() returned...
} else {
    ... q could be non-empty at this point because a consumer could
        have added new items after the peek() returned...
}
```

The peek() method is somewhat more useful if there is only one consumer.  In that case:

```
if (q.peek() != NULL) {
    ...q MUST be non-empty here, because there is no other thread that 
       could have removed anything from the queue...
}
```

---

Of course, one reason why peek() might need a lock is if you implement a *linked* queue.  You might need locking in that case to prevent the peek() method from following a bad pointer and crashing the program.

Comment: It needs a lock to make sure that no writes happen when reads are going on.

Comment: @Varun, Sure, but why do you _care_ whether writes happen when reads are going on?  It _might_ be that you care because the read could follow a bad pointer and crash your program.  But then again, maybe not:  An array-based, ring-buffer-like implementation is not likely to have that problem.  If you think that preventing other threads from modifying the queue will help a `peek()` call to return the correct value, then read my answer above to see why there is no "correct" value.

Comment: I maintain a counter which is incremented when `add()` is called and decremented when `remove()`is called. So, in `peek()` I can check if it is empty by checking this counter. Also I have two other pointers, add pointer where the new value is added, and remove pointer which points to the value that will be removed next. So, in `peek()` I return the value pointed by remove pointer.

Comment: Although, tell me this, can this type of lock end up in a deadlock? I created a JUnit for testing this "thread safe queue". Two out of three threads had the state terminated and the other one had waiting state.

Comment: @Varun, Any type of lock can participate in a deadlock, but a thread that is waiting for a lock will be in the "BLOCKED" state, not the "WAITING" state.  The "WAITING" state is for threads that are waiting for some event.  Could be waiting to read from a pipe or from a socket, could be waiting for some other thread to put something in a queue, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a solution, a quick fix would be to create a duplicate array (queue) before releasing the lock but after each update. This array could be your reference variable for peek().

I'm not sure if java supports this while threading, but you could create another variable, say query, that is a reference to the original queue. this would allow you to see updates from peek() immediately. While I'm slightly novice at java, most languages achieve this by using something like the following:

```
query = &queue;
```

The & sign is the pass by reference operator.